# Visual Studio 2013 does not create SQL Server 2014 LocalDB database

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, localdb

I am working on VB.NET project in Visual Studio 2013 Community (thanks MS). SQL Server 2014 LocalDB is setup on my machine  (just in case, went out to MS website and got latest and greatest copy of LocalDB). Added `Service-based Database` to my project. In the properties for database object, connection string is `Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;...`, which means it is using older version of database. Tried to modify connection (Server Explorer > Right click on my database > Modify Connection > Advanced > ), but none of the options point to correct server.

According to [MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202%28v=sql.120%29.aspx), correct string should be `"Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;..."`

Is anyone else facing the same issue ? Any workarounds ?

Comment: Can you connect to (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB using SQL Server Object Explorer?

Comment: Same problem here, I have not found any documentation that tells me why this is the case. Maybe the `LocalDB` Code First feature gets locked down in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

Removed the existing database. Created a new database SQL Server Management Studio 2014. Placed it in the solutions folder. Connected to that database through Server Explorer: set `Server Name:` to `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` and `Attach a database name:` to the .mdf file.

Answer (score 3):

LocalDB instances are located in the following folder:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances
```

Most likely the instance is just `V12` or `V12.0` or `ProjectsV12` (which is what I have for SQL Server 2014 LocalDB)

So, assuming you have the "ProjectV12" instance folder, the server name is:

```
(localdb)\ProjectV12
```

Comment: For the record, I recently installed SQL Server Express 2014 (with Tools) 64 bit, but my LocalDb instance is still "v11.0" at this location. I can connect to it using the "(localdb)\v11.0" server name. 

I believe this LocalDb instance is from a previous installation of SQL Server 2012 Express. To connect to the 2014 instance of LocalDb I use the connection string "(localDB)\MSSQLLocalDB".

Answer (score 2):

newprint's 'solution' above will certainly work and may make life easier in the long run.

However, I just solved the same problem more directly using directions from this post:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b75bef7e-13f3-4658-8d43-9df12ab4c320/connecting-localdb-using-sql-server-management-studio-express
Look for the 26 August 2012 answer by ReadyRoll although I'm copying his directions in below for safe-keeping.

VisualStudio does create a LocalDb instance if you create your db while working in a Visual Studio solution. However the 'server name' from Management Studio Express' point of view is a weird looking string.

From the MSDN post by ReadyRoll:

```
1. Get the address of a (localdb) instance by running the following command:

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe" info [InstanceName]
(if its the default instance you're interested in, specify v11.0 as the [InstanceName]

2. Copy the value returned in the "Instance pipe name", e.g. np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#13E05E01\tsql\query

3. Add a new server registration in SSMS and paste the "Instance pipe name" value as the Server Name.
NOTE: It is not necessary to specify "Named pipes" as the protocol. SSMS should detect the appropriate protocol for you.
```

Note: I had trouble making sense of step 3 for a while. I just pasted the string I got from running SqlLocalDb.exe into the 'server name' field in my MSE Connect to Server dialog:
[image]